# tooltip plugin with selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I use tooltip plugin with JQuery selector? 
I used this:

```
 <span class="tooltip" title="You can use letters">
```

but I want to write it with selectors, I did this:

```
 <script>
     $('#name1').ready(function() {
       Tipped.create('#name1', 'create-tooltip');
 });


     </script>
```

but it does'nt work, can anyone help me with it?

Comment: why would you need to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$('#name1').ready` with `$(document).ready`.

The purpose of using `.ready` is to safely use elements after they are present in DOM.

When you did `$('#name').ready`, element with id `name1` wasn't probably existed in the DOM, which might as well be the reason, why your code didn't work.

Comment: I want to use this tooltip only for the inpute with name1 id.. would it work if i change it?

Comment: i did that, still no resalut.. could this happen because of my includes? I think I might miss one plugin include..

Comment: @user3223551 did you add Jquery libary?

Comment: I added these: <script src="js/tipped.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="js/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/chosen.proto.js"></script>
   <script src="js/chosen.proto.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: @user3223551 include tipped __after__ jQuery; and include tipped.css too